# Vertical cofibration arrow in xypic

Tags: diagrams, arrows, xy-pic

I want to use `xypic` to make diagrams using vertical *cofibration arrows*, i.e. ones that look like `$\rightarrowtail$`.
 Naively using

`\ar@{>->}`

gives an arrow whose tail overlaps with the source object. There is an exercise in the `xyguide`
that fixes this:

`\newdir{ >}{{}*!/-5pt/@{>}}`.

But using this for vertical arrows gives tails that are horizontally shifted and do not attach to the shaft. How can I fix this or is there a nicer way to do such arrows in xypic anyway? This is the best I have seen so far but the results are not exceptional.

Here's a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\newdir{ >}{{}*!/-5pt/@{>}}

\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix{
 S_{P} \ar@{=}[r] \ar@{ >->}[d] & S_{P} \ar@{->>}[r] \ar@{ >->}[d] & 0 \ar@{ >->}[d] \\
 R' \ar@{ >->}[r] \ar@{->>}[d] & R \ar@{->>}[r] \ar@{->>}[d] & M \ar@{=}[d] \\ 
 P' \ar@{ >->}[r] & P \ar@{->>}[r] & M
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add what you have up to now?

Comment: I'm no sure what you mean. The \newdir given above is what I have. It works for horizontal arrows but not vertical ones. Do you want an example of its use?

Comment: I meant showing the code for a diagram of the kind you want, even if the arrow is wrong.

Comment: Sure. The vertical arrows here typeset incorrectly:
\[ \xymatrix{
S_{P} \ar@{=}[r] \ar@{ >->}[d] & S_{P} \ar@{->>}[r] \ar@{ >->}[d] & 0 \ar@{ >->}[d] \R' \ar@{ >->}[r] \ar@{->>}[d] & R \ar@{->>}[r] \ar@{->>}[d] & M \ar@{=}[d] \P' \ar@{ >->}[r] & P \ar@{->>}[r] & M
} \]

Comment: the arrowheads used here are very "deep".  the arrowheads that match those on the computer modern arrows are much shallower.  if you simply change your `\usepackage` line to `\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}` there will be a more reasonable gap between the arrow tails and what the arrows point from.  (not sure why `cmtip` isn't included in the `all` option; it's possible that not everyone prefers the `cm` style, and it's harder to disable an option that's been set than to add one more.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

a one-line change in your existing example, adding `cmtip` to

```
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
```

gives this result:

[image: output of original example with code change as indicated]

Answer (score 6):

As you told, from the user guide, we have `\newdir{ >}{{}*!/-7pt/\dir{>}}`.

Note the empty space before the first use of `>`.

(**Edited:** I changed the value to `-7pt`. Choose what is better to you.)

Then you use it as `\ar@{ >->}`.

See the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It seems I was missing the `\dir{>}` in the definition of the `\newdir`.

Comment: @TomHarris, there must have been a change in Xy at some point.  I have a version of the user guide from 1999 which does not include the `\dir`.

Comment: Hmm, okay, maybe that's not it; I just downloaded the up-to-date user guide and it also uses `@{>}` rather than `\dir{>}`.  Do you by chance have a `\makeatletter` before your `\newdir`?  I did, and removing it fixed the problem for me.

Comment: @Sigur: What would be the analogous code to make `\ar@{^{(}->}` not overlap so much?

Comment: @jdc, sorry, I'm not sure I'm following.

Comment: @Sigur: I have a similar issue to the one the OP has, except in my case it is the hook in an inclusion arrow, conventionally typeset in `xypic` as `\ar@{^{(}->}[r]`, which crowds the source object. I was wondering if you knew if there was an analogue to your answer which fixes this difficulty.

Comment: @jdc, consider to use `tikz-cd` since inclusion arrows in XY are too ugly.

Comment: @Sigur, that's less of an answer than a directive to ask a different question, but I still appreciate the advice. Is there a way to get the same kind of arrowheads in `tikz-cd` as I do in `xy`? I really don't like the flat arrowheads in, for example, the `tikz` code in egreg's answer.

Comment: @jdc, `tikz-cd` has a lot of possible arrow tips. See sections 1.3 and 2.2 from documentation http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd

Answer (score 4):

If you are willing to switch to `tikz-cd`, here's the same diagram:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
S_{P} \arrow[equal]{r} \arrow[tail]{d} &
 S_{P} \arrow[two heads]{r} \arrow[tail]{d} &
 0 \arrow[tail]{d} \\
R' \arrow[tail]{r} \arrow[two heads]{d} &
 R \arrow[two heads]{r} \arrow[two heads]{d} &
 M \arrow[equal]{d} \\
P' \arrow[tail]{r} & P \arrow[two heads]{r} & M
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried using your code and the equals arrows displayed as normal arrows. Any idea why?

Comment: It works here on TeXlive 2011 and Lubuntu 11.10.

Comment: I'm using whatever distribution comes with Kile on Ubuntu 13.04.